# How to set multiple Renderers on a single XYDataSet in jaspersoft reports customizer for jFreeChart

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

We have a jfreechart in jaspersoft reports community edition where we want to apply two renderers to the same DataSet.  The approach we are currently using is not working as expected.

Our current approach is as follows where we attempt to copy the DataSet from index 0 into index 1 and then set a renderer for each index.

```
xyplot.setDataset( 1, xyplot.getDataset(0) );
xyplot.setRenderer( 1, XYLineAndShapeRenderer_DashedLines );
xyplot.setRenderer( 0, xYDifferenceRenderer_GrayBand );
```

We don't get any errors, but the line is not dashed and we do get the gray band but it is not drawn correctly.

However when we comment out one or the other, they work fine on their own.

It kinda feels like the second one overwrites the first one.

Is this the right approach to setting multiple renderers on a single DataSet and if so what are we doing wrong?

Or should a different approach be taken and if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here is what finally solved it.  I was attempting to use two renderers, one for the grey band and one for the dashed lines, but I only needed to use one.

So the final code ended up being:

```
package gprCustomizer;

import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChart;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChartCustomizer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYDifferenceRenderer;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import java.awt.Color;

public class GPRCustomizations implements JRChartCustomizer {
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jrChart) {
        // Get Plot
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot)chart.getPlot();
        // Apply Gray Band Style
        XYDifferenceRenderer xYDifRnd_GrayBand = new XYDifferenceRenderer();
        xYDifRnd_GrayBand.setNegativePaint(Color.lightGray);
        xYDifRnd_GrayBand.setPositivePaint(Color.lightGray);
        xYDifRnd_GrayBand.setShapesVisible(false);
        xYDifRnd_GrayBand.setRoundXCoordinates(true);
        // Apply Dashed Style to Series 0,1
        xYDifRnd_GrayBand.setSeriesStroke(0, 
            new BasicStroke(
                2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                1.0f, new float[] {6.0f, 6.0f}, 0.0f
            )
        );
        xYDifRnd_GrayBand.setSeriesStroke(1, 
            new BasicStroke(
                2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                1.0f, new float[] {6.0f, 6.0f}, 0.0f
            )
        );
        plot.setRenderer(xYDifRnd_GrayBand);
        // Remove Borders from Legend
        if(chart.getLegend() != null)
        {
            chart.getLegend().setBorder(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);   
        }
    }
}
```

Which produced the expected outcome of the grey band and the dashed lines either side:

[image: Final Outcome]

Answer (score 2):

For the renderers to work correctly you need 2 different dataset (2:nd needs to be another object in your case a `clone` not a pointer) and 2 different renderer's (seems that you already have this).

```
XYDataset xyDataset1 = .... //I'm a dataset
XYDataset xyDataset2 = .... //I'm a another dataset if same values I need to be a clone 
                           //you can't do xyDataset2 = xyDataset1 since like this I become xyDataset1

XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
plot.setDataset(0, xyDataset1);
plot.setDataset(1, xyDataset2);
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer0 = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(); 
//do you personalizzation code
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer1 = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(); 
//do you personalizzation code
plot.setRenderer(0, renderer0); 
plot.setRenderer(1, renderer1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So XYPlot.getDataset(0) returns an XYDataSet.  DefaultXYDataSet has a clone method and DefaultXYDataSet says it implements XYDataset in the doco.  But when I tried xyplot.setDataset(1, xyplot.getDataset(0).clone()); I get a compile error The method clone() is undefined for the type XYDataset.  Do you know how I can clone an XYDataSet?

Comment: Sorry have investigated some, try ((DefaultXYDataSet)xyplot.getDataset(0)).clone(), it may fail if the series keys for example are not clonable., if the dataset is not an instance of DefaultXYDataSet you need to create the clone() by yourself... but I belive it is...

Comment: Ok I will give that a go, thanks for your time Petter, I will let you know if this works and accept the answer ;-)

Comment: Ok so it won't cast the XYDataset as a DefaultXYDataset.  Says the types aren't compatible.  The XYDataset doesn't have any methods to set a value or clone... so I guess the new question is how to clone an XYDataSet?  With not setters I can't even create a for loop to populate one.  Also XYDataSet is an interface not a class... so I think I need to find out what class object that is implementing the XYDataSet interface is actually being passed... like maybe it is a XYSeriesCollection...  I will do some testing on this in the morning.

Comment: Tyr to understand which class you have className().,.. then you cast it,  How do you construct your dataset?. however if in the end the class does not support clone it should not be very difficult to do it your self (put the same data again)....

Comment: Petter, finally got it sorted, I have posted the answer here.  Thanks for your input, much appreciated.